# 3.6 V Zener diodes clamping at 2.3 V

Tags: adc, zener

I'm scratching my head on this one:

[image]

This is a basic unity gain follower. Max. ADC input is 3.3 V. However, on my prototype boards all OUTs maxed out at 2.3 V.

So I removed D1 and D2, and then the OUTs were 3.3V as expected, all of them (5 boards).

OUTs are connected to MCU analog input pins.

Question: why is a [BZX584C3V6_R1_00001](https://www.panjit.com.tw/upload/datasheet/BZX584C2V4_SERIES.pdf) 3.6 V Zener diode clamping voltage to 2.3 V only?

Comment: What voltage do you measure at the opamp outputs (before R3 & R5)?

Comment: Zeners definitely have marking W5? Could be the wrong zener was installed.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but considering that your opamp only has a 3.3V supply, why are the zeners even necessary in that position ? They'd be more useful on the opamp inputs...

Comment: Low voltage zeners are atrocious and have high leakage at voltages much lower than the marked voltage. Look at this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274695/3-3v-zener-diode-as-clamp-not-working

Comment: Besides the zeners conducting way before voltage reaches 3.3V, what is their function? A 3.3V op-amp feeding 3.3V ADC input won't need zeners.

Comment: I'd guess that if you removed the Zeners, it wouldn't make any difference. See Spehro Pefhany's answer.

Comment: thanks, all! will try to apply ideas shared here.

Answer (score 18):

The [op-amp](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv8542.pdf) can deliver the Izt of the zener diode (5mA) with very little drop from the positive rail, however if it did the op-amp output would have to be 4.1V because of the 100Ω resistor.

The manufacturer does not supply curves for the zener, but looking at paper datasheet for a similar Toshiba part (also specified at 5mA Izt) I think it would limit at around 3.1V with a 3.3V supply on the op-amp. (I suppose you might have them there to protect against something connected to the outputs but it would be better to use a better clamp design).

But really the likely issue is that your op-amp is **oscillating like a banshee**. Even without the 100nF output capacitors that's a possible outcome from the relatively high zener capacitance (might be a couple hundred pF) but with those caps it's practically guaranteed.

You need some capacitance directly from the op-amp outputs to the inverting inputs to stabilize them.

Comment: A good first guess for capacitance to add between opamp output and inverting input would be `0.1µF * 100ohm / 1kohm = 0.01µF`, to match the pole with the zero.

Answer (score 9):

Low voltage zeners have a very soft knee. This datasheet doesn't list the current at the rated zener voltage, but another datasheet lists a current of 69 mA. This opamp can't put out anywhere near this much current.

To predict the output, you would need to create an I-V curve for both the zener and the opamp.

Edit: measured data for future reference.

[image]